# Optimizing counting characters within a string

Tags: c#, string, performance, character

I just created a simple method to count occurences of each character within a string, without taking caps into account.

```
static List<int> charactercount(string input)
        {
            char[] characters = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz".ToCharArray();
            input = input.ToLower();

            List<int> counts = new List<int>();
            foreach (char c in characters)
            {
                int count = 0;
                foreach (char c2 in input) if (c2 == c)
                    {
                        count++;
                    }

                counts.Add(count);
             }

            return counts;

        }
```

Is there a cleaner way to do this (i.e. without creating a character array to hold every character in the alphabet) that would also take into account numbers, other characters, caps, etc?

Comment: What do you mean by cleaner way? Should it look better, be faster, fewer lines of code...?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Conceptually, I would prefer to return a `Dictionary<string,int>` of counts.  I'll assume that it's ok to know by omission rather than an explicit count of 0 that a character occurs zero times, you can do it via LINQ.  @Oded's given you a good start on how to do that.  All you would need to do is replace the `Select()` with `ToDictionary( k => k.Key, v => v.Count() )`.  See my comment on his answer about doing the case insensitive grouping.  Note: you should decide if you care about cultural differences in characters or not and adjust the `ToLower` method accordingly.

You can also do this without LINQ;

```
public static Dictionary<string,int> CountCharacters(string input)
{
     var counts = new Dictionary<char,int>(StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase);

     foreach (var c in input)
     {
          int count = 0;
          if (counts.ContainsKey(c))
          {
              count = counts[c];
          }
          counts[c] = counts + 1;
     }

     return counts;
}
```

Note if you wanted a `Dictionary<char,int>`, you could easily do that by creating a case invariant character comparer and using that as the `IEqualityComparer<T>` for a dictionary of the required type.  I've used `string` for simplicity in the example.

Again, adjust the type of the comparer to be consistent with how you want to handle culture.

Answer (score 1):

Using `GroupBy` and `Select`:

```
aString.GroupBy(c => c).Select(g => new { Character = g.Key, Num = g.Count() })
```

The returned anonymous type list will contain each character and the number of times it appears in the string.

You can then filter it in any way you wish, using the static methods defined on `Char`.

Comment: `.GroupBy( c => char.ToLower(c) )` if we're ignoring case as specified.

Comment: @tvanfosson - True, though you could `.Where(c => c.IsLower)` on the resulting list. Or any other predicate...

Comment: Will be an order of magnitude slower. Not sure if the OP cares.

Comment: @usr - OP did ask to optimize for clean code... Not fast code ;)

Answer (score 0):

Your code is kind of slow because you are looping through the range a-z instead of just looping through the input.

If you only need to count letters (like your code suggests), the fastest way to do it would be:

```
int[] CountCharacters(string text)
{
    var counts = new int[26];

    for (var i = 0; i < text.Length; i++)
    {
        var charIndex - text[index] - (int)'a';
        counts[charIndex] = counts[charindex] + 1;
    }

    return counts;
}
```

Note that you need to add some thing like verify the character is in the range, and convert it to lowercase when needed, or this code might throw exceptions. I'll leave those for you to add. :)

Comment: `IndexOutOfRangeException`

Comment: @tvanfosson: Read to the end... I said this is missing verification. I don't think you always have to give the OP the complete code digested completely. I trust that he can add these verifications, and my intent was just to explain how to do it faster.

Answer (score 0):

Based on +Ran's answer to avoiding `IndexOutOfRangeException`:

```
static readonly int differ = 'a';
int[] CountCharacters(string text) {
    text = text.ToLower();
    var counts = new int[26];

    for (var i = 0; i < text.Length; i++) {
        var charIndex = text[i] - differ;
        // to counting chars between 'a' and 'z' we have to do this:
        if(charIndex >= 0 && charIndex < 26)
            counts[charIndex] += 1;
    }
    return counts;
}
```

Actually using `Dictionary` and/or `LINQ` is not optimized enough as counting chars and working with a low level array.